# How do you displaying button on multiple ribbon bars in Outlook?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I created a simple button for a Outlook ribon bar in Visual Baic .NET using the Ribon designer. Is there a way to get that button to show in multible bars? I tried with generic "OfficeId" and selecting multible RibbonTypes (where i want it to show). As long as I type the correct officeId it will show where I want but I want it to show up any time you are writeing or repplying to a email.

I tried TabNewMailMessage for example and others. TabNewMailMessage only works when you pop out the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the `RibbonType` property values where you would like to see your ribbon customizations:

[image: RibbonType]

To add ribbon controls to the Explorer window you need to select the `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer` entry from the list.

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Comment: I tried that before posting and had no luck. It shows up when I do a pop-out of the reply, but not when I click reply and end type inside the preview area. Other add-ins I use (like Gramerly) show up both ways. I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: You need to select the `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer` entry in that case.